# Modified cable for Ender 5+ LCD touchscreen

Tags: electronics, creality-ender-5, lcd-screen

I wanted to upgrade my Ender 5 plus to a silent board as it makes a lot of noise. So I chose the BTT SKR 3 EZ board and started to configure it. However, in the Marlin configuration, there was a README explaining that the LCD must be flashed, which makes sense.
The thing is, it also says:

> The LCD will need the cable modified to fit the SKR 3 motherboard.
> Four pins, tx2-pa10 rx2-pa9 gnd-g 5v-+5v, (See the boards silkscreens for pin labels)

I found the TX2, RX2, GND, and +5 V on the LCD (as in the picture) but have no clue what is pa10 and pa9...

[image: Photo of an LCD Pin header with labels for the individual pins]

Note:
After flashing the LCD, when I connect it back to the ancient board, it lights up with the Marlin logo for a few seconds and then goes off. When using the SKR 3 EZ (flashed of course) nothing happen as I didn't change the cabbling yet.

Comment: By putting SOLVED in the title without answering your own question or upvoting and/or accepting an answer, the question is not solved. I've reverted the question to the prior last edit. Please take the [tour] and look into [help] to learn how SE sites work.

Answer (score 1):

> but have no clue what is pa10 and pa9...

These are identifiers for the microprocessor pins. You find these two in the TFT header on the right in the image below:

[image]